# How could a Wormhole be transported?

Tags: science-based, technology, black-holes, wormholes

In my universe, humanity has learned how to open wormholes for transportation, how they are opened is irrelevant and can be hand-waved, what must be kept in mind is that when they are opened, two ends appear near each other.

Assuming a stable Schwarzschild-like wormhole, that is essentially a black hole, how could one of its ends be transported? Preferably in a spaceship?

I would like a more science-based answer. While it doesn't need to be possible in real life, I just would like to make the hand-waving less brutal.

Edit.
It is previously stated that it is a stable wormhole in the second paragraph, so evaporation should not be a concern and is out of the scope of this question. Again, the means by which it is created are also irrelevant. Just assume a regular Schwarzschild wormhole, or even a black hole if needed. Most aspects of this issue are out of the scope of this question, I just need a means to explain how to transport it for a particular chapter of the story, everything else is either dealt with or handwaved.

To anyone who thinks that what I'm asking is unclear, please re-read the title and assume a standard Schwarzschild wormhole. To anyone downvoting this, please re-read the question.

Comment: We don't have any working theory on creation, anchoring etc of wormholes. Can you tell us how does it work in your story? If you can, answer consistent with your rules can probably be found. If not, I highly doubt this is answerable. Or maybe it boils down to "how to transport small wormhole that somehow does not evaporate with hawking radiation?" maybe?

Comment: I'd probably take a look at how to transport stars. Unfortunately, the most promising possibility (the stellar engine) requires your object to be outputting a star's worth of radiation. As @Molot said, something small will undoubtedly evaporate pretty quickly.

Comment: I'm seeing this in the re-open queue. You talk about a 'regular Schwarzschild wormhole' as if it is a real thing. It is not. It is a mathematical construct that is a possible solution to a theory that hasn't been proven to exist. The community decided in closing your question, that you need to explain what an Schwarzschild wormhole is in order to answer whether it can be moved or not. If you can't explain what a Scharzschild is, and how it is kept open, then how can we be expected to answer?

Comment: Ravi, you didn't understand @Molot.  Present-day theoretical physics has (a) no idea how to create a wormhole and (b) no idea how to keep it stable - but you're asking (c) how to move it.  If we can't plausibly answer (a) or (b), what makes you think anyone can plausibly answer (c)?  That's why I VTCd the question as unclear... If you explained how you answered (a) and (b) then we could come up with ideas for (c).  If you won't explain, then reopening the question will only get it closed again as "primarily opinion-based" because no one idea will be better than any other.

Comment: @kingledion The OP said assuming a Schwarzschild wormhole. It may be a mathematical construct, but in the OP's world it is effectively real. There are better choices of wormholes.

Comment: @JBH Re-read the question. It is obvious the OP knows the conceptual limitations involved. The wormhole is assumed to be real in his world to make it more plausible. Theoretical physicists wouldn't have any trouble in devising plausible ways of moving wormholes. The Schwarszchild wormhole isn't the best option for a traversable spacetime shortcut.

Comment: @a4android I think my point is that 'how do I move a mathematical construct' is an underspecified question, in my mind. I would argue that it isn't reasonable that there exists someone with a.) a sufficient understanding of the mathematical implications of a Schwarzchild wormhold and b.) is active on this site.

Comment: @a4android, I've read the question a number of times throughout the day and, frankly, I doubt the OP understands the conceptual limitations.  I also support Kingledion's conclusion completely.  If it's reasonable that the question, as stated, should be opened, then it belongs on physics.SE or astronomy.SE.  If kingledion and HDE226868 haven't posted answers, I doubt anyone on the site will.

Comment: @kingledion It isn't about moving mathematical construct. That would be interesting in & of itself in an amusing way. The question assumes the existence of a Schwarzschild wormhole (SW) as a real thing  then it is more about moving a physical object that is the equivalent of a SW. It isn't about understanding the mathematics. Enough information is accessible to answer it and could be answered here. JBH's suggestion about Physics SE might be better fit does make sense.

Comment: @JBH I think you have misread the question. You're not alone in this. This is in seeing what is being asked & understanding its assumptions. I agree Physics SE might be better fit. They might trip over its worldbuilding aspects. Nobody on the site can answer the question? Well I can.

Comment: You're a brave man, @a4android.  How you can describe moving something without knowing how it came to be or why it's where it shouldn't be takes chutzpah.  I'm voting to reopen.  Hold your breath.  I suspect if your answer will be viewed with a microscope.

Comment: I don't need a plausible answer, again, as previously stated, it doesn't need to be possible IRL, or mathematicaly accurate, also previously stated, it just needs to make hand waving less forced. Again, I have not come with accurate means to create one in the story either.

Comment: @JBH Not brave. I know what I know about wormholes. If WBers want to criticize my answer very are welcome to do so, but they will be batting against the proposals of *real* scientists.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, RaviMattar, I am sorry my colleagues have given you a "warm welcome". Their reasons for doing so are in the belief this will improve your question. The handwaving went over their heads. My advice is that your scenario won't work for a Schwarszchild or as you put it, a Schwarszchild-like wormhole. Firstly, it won't work in away best suited as a spacetime shortcut. Secondly, it comes with a black hole (BH) and moving BHs is extremely difficult. Not impossible, extremely difficult.

Comment: By the Gods, so it's true, nice people really do exist here. Thank you for all your help. And thank you for actually trying to answer my question, I've lurked for awhile here before even attempting to open a question. As for the WH, I guess I have to either hand-wave it or open then on spot. The thing is I really see how they're widespread in sci-fi, but I can't find virtually anything on the internet when it comes to transporting them (I guess it doesn't help that I'm stuck on just my cell for some time).

Comment: Why do you think wormhole can be transported? Are you thinking about packaging a wormhole (or dense matter) and transport it? How do your "wormhole creator" works? Is it as simple as "I have one wormhole here that is programmed to connect to the wormhole there, so now I want to transport this end to somewhere else"

Comment: Or your machine creates a wormhole by converting energy into matter at one point, which then can be programmed to connect to some other wormholes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Gravity

Wormholes are affected by gravity (I think), since in general relativity, gravity is geometric phenomenon. Therefore, what you basically need is some heavy object to pull the wormhole where you want.

(Note that you probably won't be able to have it on the ship though. You will be "towing" it.)

Comment: I guess I could work with that, this could even justify "artificial gravity" that doesn't rely on centripetal force.

Comment: @RaviMattar you could use a black hole powered spaceship as the energy source.